# Documentation Review error 500, when loading next item in queue

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues, documentation-review

I am encountering a 500 error when trying to get the next item in documentation queue.

The steps I followed,

1. Open documentation review queue. The first item that popped up was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/102803)
2. I pressed `Skip` and then the

   > An error has occurred - please try your action again.
3. Instead of `Skip`, I now have the `Next` button visible, which when clicked yields the same error as before.

I am using the latest stable Chrome on windows 10 and the error from the developer tool is the following,

> GET https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/review/changes/next 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> docs-transpiled.en.js?v=478c91846042:7

Also now when I am trying to open the Documentation review queue I have this error.

[image]

**Update**
The issue seems to be random. There are cases that I can successfully review 3 or 4 changes before the issue appears again.

Comment: console.log('Message to documentation developers').

Comment: I still see the same errors with documentation review. If I click on the link in '1' above and then click "next", or if trying to browse to the documentation review queue via the review page.

Comment: @Toby Hmm strange, I just test it again and I have no errors now.

Comment: @Athafoud Im still seeing it, though my recent edits are getting reviewed (slower than normal I think?) so seems like it's affecting some folks and not others? I have the same issue if I try from a private browsing window though.

Comment: I think I've figured out how to consistently reproduce this. The error appears whenever you try to load the next/first review task and the queue is empty.

Comment: @RamenChef I am 80% sure that you are right! I need to check it a couple of times more and I will update accordingly.

Comment: Okay, after a bit more review, it seems like that's not the only thing that causes it. But it does seem to stop spouting error messages if you take a direct link to a task.